# Unable to get itemCategory info from call GetConfiguration when called from golang

Tags: go, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

The api call

```
GET https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Package/257/getConfiguration?objectMask=mask[itemCategory]
```

returns an object, `[]datatypes.Product_Package_Order_Configuration` where `ItemCategory` is populated. 
sample output:

```
{
"id": 7167,
"isRequired": 0,
"itemCategoryId": 390,
"orderStepId": 1,
"packageId": 257,
"sort": 0,
"itemCategory": {
"categoryCode": "trusted_platform_module",
"id": 390,
"name": "Server Security",
"quantityLimit": 1,
"sortOrder": 0
}
},
```

When I attempt the same call in go, `itemCategory` is not populated, even though I declare it in the mask. Please advise.

```
package main

import (
"fmt"
"github.com/softlayer/softlayer-go/services"
"github.com/softlayer/softlayer-go/session"
"encoding/json"
)

func main() {
    // SoftLayer API username and key
    username := "set-me"
    apikey   := "set-me"

    // Create a session
    sess := session.New(username, apikey)

    // Enable debug
    sess.Debug = true

    // Get SoftLayer_Account service
    service := services.GetProductPackageService(sess)

    // Object-Mask to get specific Vlan's information
    mask := "itemCategory"

    // Call to getNetworkVlans in order to retrieve vlans according to filter.
    result, err := service.Mask(mask).Id(257).GetConfiguration()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("\n Unable to retrieve config:\n - %s\n", err)
        return
    }

    // Following helps to print the result in json format.
    jsonFormat, jsonErr := json.MarshalIndent(result,"","     ")
    if jsonErr != nil {
        fmt.Println(jsonErr)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(string(jsonFormat))
}
```

sample output:

```
->>>Request:
2018/05/09 09:24:36 POST /xmlrpc/v3.1/SoftLayer_Product_Package HTTP/1.1
Host: api.softlayer.com
User-Agent: Go-http-client/1.1
Content-Length: 1055
Content-Type: text/xml
Accept-Encoding: gzip

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><methodCall><methodName>getConfiguration</methodName><params><param><value><struct><member><name>headers</name><value><struct><member><name>User-Agent</name><value><string>softlayer-go/v0.1.0-alpha (go1.9.2;amd64;darwin)</string></value></member><member><name>authenticate</name><value><struct><member><name>username</name><value><string>[[SL_USER]]</string></value></member><member><name>apiKey</name><value><string>[[SL_APIKEY]]</string></value></member></struct></value></member><member><name>SoftLayer_Product_PackageInitParameters</name><value><struct><member><name>id</name><value><int>257</int></value></member></struct></value></member><member><name>SoftLayer_Product_PackageObjectMask</name><value><struct><member><name>mask</name><value><struct><member><name>itemCategory</name><value><array><data></data></array></value></member></struct></value></member></struct></value></member></struct></value></member></struct></value></param></params></methodCall>
2018/05/09 09:24:36 


<<<-Response:
2018/05/09 09:24:36 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/xml
Date: Wed, 09 May 2018 14:24:36 GMT
Server: Apache
Softlayer-Total-Items: 39
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
```

Then a string of html with the same data as below is returned
Sample entry:

```
{
          "id": 7167,
          "isRequired": 0,
          "itemCategoryId": 390,
          "orderStepId": 1,
          "packageId": 257,
          "sort": 0
     },
```

Comment: The example API call that is working just had `itemCategory` whereas the go code has nested attributes, have you tried it with just `itemCategory`?

Comment: Good point Iain. Yes I have tried that as well, to no avail. The output is the same. No itemCategory. I have changed the mask in my post to just itemCategory.

Comment: Are you using the linux operating system.

Comment: To know what is happening you have to enable the debug.
To enable the debug you have to add this line of code "sess.Debug = true" after creating the session, like this example:
sess: = session.New (username, apikey)
sess.Debug = true

Run the code and send the result.

Comment: I am running this code on my mac. I have edited my original post with your request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default endpoint is REST but in your environment you are using xmlrpc, which is probably due to the existence of the ~ / .softlayer file and in this it is configured as an XMLRPC enpoint.

For more information you can see the following documentation:
https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-go

This issue happens for the XMLRPC enpoint and you can report it in the go GitHub.
https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-go/issues/

Try in your code with the REST endpoint, like this example:

```
endpoint := "https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3"

// Create a session
sess := session.New(username, apikey, endpoint)
```

Comment: Thanks Ojeda, raised issue: https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-go/issues/100
I also posted your response in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47641717/how-to-add-object-mask-to-call-getnetworkvlans-using-golang/50256921#50256921 I had the same issue here.