# Key missing inspite of defining object mask

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying query `GetNetworkStorageService` with the following mask

```
volumeSnapshotInfoMask string = `id,notes,nasType,username,capacityGb,snapshotCapacityGb,snapshotCount,manualSnapshotCount,activeTransactionCount,
snapshots[id,notes,nasType,snapshotSizeBytes,snapshotCreationTimestamp],
manualSnapshots[id,notes,nasType,snapshotSizeBytes,snapshotCreationTimestamp]`
```

I can see some fields missing from the response I get: for eg: activeTransactionCount, snapshotCreationTimestamp. Is this because we don't have this infomration in softlayer? or there is something wrong with the query I am making? How does softlayer API behaves? Does it not show the default value for the fields missing? I am basically looking for ActiveTransactionCount field.

From what I understand is if `ActiveTransactionCount = 0` the field is missing from the response.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be the endpoint you are using in your environment, try in your code adding the REST endpoint option, like below example:

```
username := "set-me"
apikey   := "set-me"
endpoint := "https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3"

// Create a session
sess := session.New(username, apikey, endpoint)
```

For more information you can see the following links:

[Unable to get itemCategory info from call GetConfiguration when called from golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50241215/unable-to-get-itemcategory-info-from-call-getconfiguration-when-called-from-gola)

https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-go